# how to get Deffered from DAO?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to get Kotlin Coroutnies Deffered from DAO

```
@Query("select * from gameprocess where cabinId = :cabinId ")
fun getAllGameProccesBiCabin(cabinId :Int) : Deferred<GameProcess>
```

but it does not compile (room does not know how to handle Deffered), but I need to use 'wait' from 'Deffered'   how can do this?

as another option I could use extension function from this post but, dont know how to integrate it into dao:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5

Comment: saw it but did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is dependency which allows me to use `async{}.await` https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md

The problem was that I was using old version which doesn't support it.